# Process returned - 1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, matrix

I am beginner in C. I got this error and I can not figure out how to fix it. I am using Code:blocks and GNU GCC compiler. It is simple matrix that has to be sorted using Shaker sort. I can not continue until i make this working. Please help me guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r=11, s=23, m[r][s], i, j, pom;

    printf("Generated matrix:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            m[i][j]=rand()%100;
            printf("%3d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    do{
        if(m[i][j]>=m[i+1][j+1])
        {
            pom=m[i+1][j+1];
            m[i+1][j+1]=m[i][j];
            m[i][j]=pom;
        }

        if(j==s)
        {
            i++;
            j=0;
        }

        if(i==r&&j==s)
            break;
        j++;
    }while(1);

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            m[i][j]=rand()%100;
            printf("%3d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Yeah guys I had it completely wrong. Now I do not get this error anymore but I do not understand why I can not get highest number to m[r][s]. I always get the exact same matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r=11, s=23, m[r][s], i, j, pom;

    printf("Generated matrix:\n\n");
    for(i = 0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<s;j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand()%100;
            printf("%3d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    i=0;
    pom=0;

    for(j=0;j=s;j++){
        if(m[i][j]>=m[i][j+1])
        {
            pom = m[i][j+1];
            m[i][j+1] = m[i][j];
            m[i][j] = pom;
        }

        if(i==r&&j==s)
            break;

        if(j==s)
        {
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<s;j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man 3 exit` and `man 2 exit` The result is a bitmask, only the lower bits constitute the actual exit() value, the rest is formed by the reason why the process exited. BTW: use some whitespace around your '=' operators.

Comment: That's error code for access violation. In your do-while loop, look carefully at what happens when `i==r && j==s`. Hint: you hit your second `if` first, which does something to `i` and `j`...

Comment: Judging by the sorting logic, it seems entirely conceivable the access violation you're exiting with is accurate. Using integrated `gdb` would help, though no-more-so than walking your algorithm on paper and remembering that an array of dimension N is indexible from 0..N-1. If your test of `if (j==s)` were ever true it means you already violated that indexing premise and your program is ill-formed (which it is).

Comment: `j` is incremented at the end of the do-while loop and not checked before using it on the next iteration. And the only check on `i` is when `j` is at limit too, with `if(i==r&&j==s) break;`. Which will never happen because when you increment `i` you reset `j`. Finally, your matrix manipulation is foiled by a repeat of its initial randomisation.

Comment: In your new edit the swap loop is now `for(j=0;j=s;j++)` which tests the end condition `j=s` before executing the loop. But `j=s` is not a test but an assignment which not only sets `j` out of range of the matrix array but evaluates as `true` for the loop. Every iteration, `j` is out of range of the matrix, and `i` is incremented until the loop only ends when the `break` is hit. I could say you need `for(j=0;j<s;j++)` but that's not right either. Within the loop you are incorrectly fiddling with `i` and `j` when you should you be using two nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still include the fundamental error at line `25`:

```
// for(j=0;j=s;j++){
```

should be:

```
for(j=0;j<s;j++){
```

Compiling with **warnings** enabled would have disclosed this error right away. Whenever you compile your code with `gcc`, at **minimum** you should enable `-Wall -Wextra` warnings. They will save you a lot of time. Example:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/mtrxerr mtrxerr.c
```

Correcting just that error, provides the following output with the matrices changing as they should. However, your sort still needs additional work. Here is an example of the output:

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/mtrxerr
Generated matrix:

 69 41 30 55 44 78 67 30 81 14 92 62 21 91 66 21 28 98 69 30 90 43 57
 12 35 85 21 49 45 31 40 14 24 70 22 68  0 89 50 81 56 42 44 77 33 62
 98 14 61 19 96  3 14 54 15 50 91 88 51 36 71 91 50 95 62 24 15 62 66
 66 96 22  8 40 51 94 54  1  8 67 21  4 70 35 10 37 85  1 78 36 37 49
 80 40 97 42 64 12 56 30 78 52  4 39 44 55 85 51 57 93 18 78 49 41 65
 60 78 51 13 56 39 51 58 19 91 55 13  7 67 22 90 98 74 94 89 71  2 74
 22 59 19 92 89 68 33 54 80 12 57 94 20 49 97 78 20 40 33 34 47 53  8
 89  3 82 84 92  5 38 66 79 97 85 72 38  5 57 44 38 21  2 84 42  3 81
 72 23 21  6  9 20 11 17 10 14 52 46  6  9 84 24 89 33 61 13 71 66 70
 67 56 92 69 40 86 24 21 58  0 94 16 61 15 27 79 77 93 83 23 99 92 59
 75 33 92 36 46 15 55 69 82 11 13  4 52 99 28 73 57 80 68 26 42 35 53


 41 30 55 44 69 67 30 78 14 81 62 21 91 66 21 28 92 69 30 90 43 57 12
 98 35 85 21 49 45 31 40 14 24 70 22 68  0 89 50 81 56 42 44 77 33 62
 98 14 61 19 96  3 14 54 15 50 91 88 51 36 71 91 50 95 62 24 15 62 66
 66 96 22  8 40 51 94 54  1  8 67 21  4 70 35 10 37 85  1 78 36 37 49
 80 40 97 42 64 12 56 30 78 52  4 39 44 55 85 51 57 93 18 78 49 41 65
 60 78 51 13 56 39 51 58 19 91 55 13  7 67 22 90 98 74 94 89 71  2 74
 22 59 19 92 89 68 33 54 80 12 57 94 20 49 97 78 20 40 33 34 47 53  8
 89  3 82 84 92  5 38 66 79 97 85 72 38  5 57 44 38 21  2 84 42  3 81
 72 23 21  6  9 20 11 17 10 14 52 46  6  9 84 24 89 33 61 13 71 66 70
 67 56 92 69 40 86 24 21 58  0 94 16 61 15 27 79 77 93 83 23 99 92 59
 75 33 92 36 46 15 55 69 82 11 13  4 52 99 28 73 57 80 68 26 42 35 53
```

You have been advised in the comments that the sort algorithm will require nested loops. Take a look at your sort routine and correct the logic. An example of the routine [**Cocktail (shaker) Sort**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Cocktail_sort) is available in many places on the web. Another example is: [**Cocktail Sort Algorithm or Shaker Sort Algorithm**](http://www.codingunit.com/cocktail-sort-algorithm-or-shaker-sort-algorithm).

After fixing your sort routine, if you still have problems, drop a comment and we will be glad to provide additional help.

Comment: Thank you, but I am really desperate right now. I realised we can use only one outer cycle and one inner cycle. Also we can use only one array. I have really big trouble solving this assignment. I accept any advices.